# Rectangular shape behind text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a very simple design in CSS. I have a title and a paragraph. I need to add a rectangle behind it, so that the text overflows this rectangle.

Something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/L95Wr.png

I tried many different things, one solution I made is :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">

  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>
      This is the title
    </h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph paragraphparagraphpararrrrrgrapaaaaaaaaaah.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
}

.main {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bcsg6q03/3/

But I need a better solution. This one relies on margin-top: -150px; So everything moves if I change the text or the rectangle size.

Is there's a better way to do so ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `:before` and `left`

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

.main {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top:15px;
}

.main:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  left:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>
      This is the title
    </h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph paragraphparagraphpararrrrrgrapaaaaaaaaaah.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this is a clean way to do it. Thanks a lot, it works perfectly

Comment: @Remi glat it helped

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>
      This is ddddddddddddthe title
    </h1>
    <p>This is a pardddddddddddddddddddddddddddddagraphaaaaah.</p>
</div>

.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-size: 80% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
 }
```

Comment: The background will auto adjust with the text... adjust background horizontal size and container vertical padding as you wish

Comment: It works but it's not very elegent and I need something more flexible. But thanks for your answer !

Comment: I agree, not the most straightforward solution, since you have to edit then encode the svg element whenever and update is required

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yo6aetcw/)

```css
.main {
    width: 300px;
    height:140px;
    min-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid lightgray;
    padding:10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this won't work. I need the text to go out of the rectangle, that's why I was struggling with it.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
}

.main {
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>
        This is the title
      </h1>
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: then give width 100% to the rectangle or use overflow hidden

Comment: That still doesn't work. Also, text only answers are generally *very* bad answers since they don't offer an explanation to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

first make the `rectangle` inside `container`, give it `position: absolute` and `left:calc(50% - 90px)` with 90px being half its `width`
https://jsfiddle.net/qr7z5eou/